# PySimpleGUI: index of column/frames

Tags: pysimplegui

I made a gui in PySimpleGUI and created 3 columns but when i try to add a fourth one it goes on the other column and does [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnseU.png).I want that the column where i store the buttons stays in his position. Here 's the code too. Is it possible to change the index? Here another image to let you see how the work should [be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGMHp.png) the only difference is that i want to add colc(the name of the column) to stay in the white part.

```py
# Import delle liberie
from config import *
import tkinter as tk
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime
font = ("Times New Roman", 11)
#import di tkinter per 
x = tk.Tk()
x.withdraw()
now = datetime.datetime.now()
time=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
width = x.winfo_screenwidth()
height = x.winfo_screenheight()
size = (140, height)
size1 = (width, 100)

colc= [
    [sg.Text("testo"), sg.Input()],
    [sg.Text("testo"), sg.Input()],
    [sg.Text("testo"), sg.Input()],
    [sg.Text("testo"), sg.Input()],
    [sg.Text("testo"), sg.Input()]
]

inputbottom = [
   [sg.Text("Input →", background_color="blue"), sg.Input(size=(209, 50))],
   
    
    ]

logo = [
        
        [sg.Image(filename ='img/logo.png', background_color="blue")],
              
        
    ]

col1 = [ 
           
           [sg.Text(time, justification="c", background_color="blue", key='-TEXT-')],
           [sg.Button("Avvia Standard", size=(14, 6), button_color=('gray'),)],
           [sg.Button("Avvia Multipla", size=(14, 6), button_color=('gray'))],
           [sg.Button("Concludi Singola", size=(14, 6), button_color=('gray'))],
           [sg.Button("Concludi tutto", size=(14, 6), button_color=('gray'))],
           [sg.Button("Mostra Attive", size=(14, 6), button_color=('gray'))],
           [sg.Button("Login", size=(14, 6), button_color=('gray'),)],
           [sg.Button("Logout", size=(14, 6), button_color=('gray'))]
           ]

frametop = [[sg.Column(logo, background_color='Blue')]]
buttons =  [[sg.Column(col1,background_color='Blue')]]



layout = [
        
        [sg.Column(frametop, size=size1, background_color='Blue', justification="top", pad=(0, 0))],
        [sg.Column(colc, pad=(0,0))],
        [sg.Column(buttons, size=(140, 845), background_color='Blue', justification="right", pad=(0, 0))],
        [sg.Column(inputbottom, justification="top", background_color="Blue", size=(width, 400), pad=(0,0))],
        
        
          ] 

window = sg.Window('CMF-GESTIONALE',layout,resizable=True, finalize=True,size=(width, height),icon='img/Icona.ico',background_color='white', font=font,margins=(0,0)).Finalize()
window.Maximize()

# Eventi Bottoni
while True:
    
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Logout':
        break
    if event == 'Avvia Standard':
        print("-")
    if event == 'Avvia Multipla':
        print("-")
    if event == 'Concludi Singola':
        print("-")
    if event == 'Concludi tutto':
        print("-")
    if event == 'Mostra Attive':
        print("-")
    if event == 'Login':
        print("-")
    
     
window.close()
```

Comment: It depend on how you split you GUI as combination of horizontal block and vertical block. Add option `, justification="right"` into `[sg.Column(colc, pad=(0,0))],` to shift colc to right. You may set another for `col1` and `colc` for alignment of both layouts.

Comment: i made one vertical bar and one horizontal and another vertical on the bottom. Is there a way to add the fourt one in the center wihout givin me that white space?

Comment: @JasonYang it doesn t work either. I tried to sarch online but i can t find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need layout with left column and right column, example code here

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

left = [[sg.Text("testo"), sg.Input()] for i in range(5)]
right = [[sg.Button(f"Button {i}")] for i in range(10)]
layout = [
    [sg.Text("Top Line")],
    [sg.Column(left, vertical_alignment='top'), sg.Column(right, vertical_alignment='top')],
    [sg.Text("Bottom Line")],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```